# Segmentation Fault while implementing a C program for sorting

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm developing a program to sort an XML file that contains an open dictionary. I'm trying to do this using flex to recognize words, tags and etc and linked lists in C to sort them. By now I have a linked list to sort every word alphabetically and I tried to do the same to sort those words inside the usage that each word corresponds. I'm having the segmentation problem, probably because the list is getting a NULL I think from the `InsertUsageWord()` function, where did I go wrong?
Thanks in advance.

C code

```
typedef struct _dicio {
        char *usg, *orth, *def; //uso, palavra e definicao
        struct _dicio *next;
} dicio;

typedef struct _usage {
    char *word;
    struct _usage *unext;
} usage;

usage* InsertUsageWord(usage* ulista, char *palavra) {
    usage *unode = (usage*)malloc(sizeof(usage));
    unode->word = strdup(palavra);
    unode->unext = ulista;
    return unode;
}

dicio* InsertWord(dicio* lista, char *utilizacao, char *ortografia, char *definicao) {
        dicio *node = (dicio*)malloc(sizeof(dicio));
        node->usg = strdup(utilizacao);
        node->orth = strdup(ortografia);
        node->def = strdup(definicao);
        node->next = lista;
        return node;
}

void ListWord(usage* ulista, dicio* lista) {
        if(ulista == NULL) return;
        printf("%s", ulista->word);
    List(lista, ulista->word);
    ListWord(ulista->unext, lista);
}

void List(dicio* lista, char* usg) {
        if(lista == NULL) return;
        if (strcmp(usg, lista->usg) == 0 ) {printf("%s", lista->usg);}
    List(lista->next, usg);
}
```

Flex code

```
        #include "dictp16.c"
        char *word;
        char *palavra;
        char *utilizacao;
        char *definicao;
        dicio *dicionario = NULL;
        usage *use = NULL;

LETRAS [a-zA-ZÁÉÍÓÚÀÌüçÇãáíéóúàâôêõ. -;,()_]+

%x ORT USG DEF
%%
\<orth\>                                { BEGIN(ORT); }
<ORT>{LETRAS}                               { palavra = strdup(yytext); }
<ORT>\<\/orth\>                             { BEGIN(INITIAL); }

\<usg\ type=\"[a-z]+\"\>                        { BEGIN(USG); }
<USG>{LETRAS}                               { utilizacao = strdup(yytext); }
<USG>\<\/usg\>                              { use = InsertUsageWord(use, word);
                                         BEGIN(INITIAL); }

\<def\>                                 { BEGIN(DEF); }
<DEF>{LETRAS}                               { definicao = strdup(yytext); }
<DEF>\n                                 {;}
<DEF>.                                  {;}
<DEF>\<\/def\>                              { dicionario = InsertWord(dicionario, utilizacao, palavra, definicao);  
                                              BEGIN(INITIAL); }
\n                                  {}   
<<EOF>>                                 { ListWord(use, dicionario);  return 0; }
.                                   {;}
%%
```

Expected output would be something like this:

```
ant:
- Alampi~ao: O mesmo que _lampi~ao_. Cf. B. Pereira, _Pros´odia_, vb. _polymixus_.
- An^espera: O mesmo que _n^espera_. Cf. B. Pereira, _Prosodia_, vb. _pytmena_.
- Arraba¸ca: Planta, o mesmo que _raba¸ca_.
...
Pop.
- Achafundar: Enterrar no logo; meter no fundo da ´agua.
- Acarditar: O mesmo que _acreditar_.
- Alampi~ao: O mesmo que _lampi~ao_. Cf. B. Pereira, _Pros´odia_, vb. _polymixus_.
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using flex to parse XML??

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Which line is it crashing on and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `InsertUsageWord(use, word);`with `word` which is not initialized. Did you wanted to call it with `utilizacao` instead, by any chance? As it has just been initialized with a `malloc()` through `strdup()`!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

> use = InsertUsageWord(use, word);

but you never initialized word to anything